# Symfony ошибка с dotoenv

Tags: php, symfony, openserver

пытаюсь запустить проект на open server и вылезает вот такая ошибка.

```
 ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "W:\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env" environment file. in W:\domains\my.loc\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 565
( ! ) Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "W:\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env" environment file. in W:\domains\my.loc\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 565
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  395368  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0004  401368  require_once( 'W:\domains\my.loc\vendor\autoload_runtime.php )  ...\index.php:5
3   0.0212  2749440 Symfony\Component\Runtime\SymfonyRuntime->__construct( $options = ['project_dir' => 'W:\\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc/'] )    ...\autoload_runtime.php:23
4   0.0230  2972104 Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->bootEnv( $path = 'W:\\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env', $defaultEnv = 'dev', $testEnvs = [0 => 'test'] )  ...\SymfonyRuntime.php:102
5   0.0231  2972200 Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv( $path = 'W:\\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env', $envKey = 'APP_ENV', $defaultEnv = 'dev', $testEnvs = [0 => 'test'] ) ...\Dotenv.php:157
6   0.0232  2972296 Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load( $path = 'W:\\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env' ) ...\Dotenv.php:114
7   0.0232  2972672 Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad( $overrideExistingVars = FALSE, $paths = [0 => 'W:\\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env'] )    ...\Dotenv.php:92
```

Туплю и не понимаю что делать, dotenv установлен все компоненты обновил

Comment: ничего странного в пути к файлу не замечаете `W:\/Program Files (x86)/OpenServer/domains/my.loc//.env` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon Но как его изменить? это же файлы которые генерируются сами

Comment: я бы посоветовал переустановить ваш опенсервер в другую директорию вне програмфайлс, тут возможно какая то проблема с правами может возникать